# Do the isomorphic apps implies back and front stand together?

Tags: isomorphic-javascript, angular2-universal

I've been getting into isomorphic applications development with [Angular 2 Universal](https://github.com/angular/universal) but there is this thing that i cannot get clear in my head.

My understanding is that keeping back and front sides on different modules is a good practice, but it doesn't seem to be a common pattern when working with `MEAN` applications.

So, i am about to start a project that could scale and i'd want to implement the server side rendering in a future but i don't know which approach i should go with. Honestly i feel more comfortable keeping both backend and frontend on separate but, if so, **will it be possible to implement server-side rendering later on**?

Besides, supposing that i duplicate the `index.html` in both sides, will the server be able to delegate the control to the client when the first server rendering is completed? I mean, i can't imagine how that would that delegation work given the fact that they are not in the same project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, you are talking about rendering the UI and this is frontend part of your application, even if you do the pre-rendering work on the server.

This pre-rendering is only optimization, you can keep it in some separate code layer, but I believe that the whole idea of the isomorphic javascript is to re-use the same code on the client and server. This way trying to duplicate code and/or templates is not a good idea (it never is).

If you really want to keep things separated, think on splitting your application into more services:

- backend server application - some kind of rest API on top of the database which holds all the business logic (first node.js application)
- frontend server application - another node.js application which gets data from API via HTTP requests and does server-side pre-rendering (second node.js application)
- frontend - all the code running in browser

This way, initially the "frontend server application" can be simple proxy between the "frontend" and "backend server application".
Later on you can extend it with server-side rendering.

Important note: if you are going to develop application without pre-rendering on the server and add this on a later stage, you need to take into account that not all the browser-side javascript features will work on the server (for example, manipulations with native DOM elements), see the [best practices section in angular universal readme](https://github.com/angular/universal#best-practices).

Comment: Thanks for responding. Let me get tihs straight: the backend server will do the initial rendering (counting on the `frontend` module), and then it will delegate that rendering management to the frontend server (also counting on that `frontend` module)? Please correct me if i am wrong. Also, is it possible to delegate that rendering management  between separated modules? Just for the little bit that i've been getting into this with `Angular 2 Universal`, it seems like in order to accomplish this you have to keep both back and front together (i am novice btw so take it with a pinch of salt).

Comment: In regular app you already have the backend and frontend together, because backend sends the frontend code (html, CSS, JavaScript). So your backed anyway does some pre-rendering (even if this is just an empty HTML page and the rest is done on the client).
Angular universal allows you to run the frontend code on the server to do more pre-rendering. But in general the process is the same - server does something and then sends html, CSS, js code to the client. There is no some special "delegation", just the initial html page received by browser is not empty anymore.

Comment: I got it now! Thank you very much!

Comment: @jscherman also if you are going to develop application without pre-rendering on the server and add this on a later stage, you need to take into account that not all the browser-side javascript features will work on the server (for example, manipulations with native DOM elements), see the [best practices section in angular universal readme](https://github.com/angular/universal#best-practices). So you need to avoid using these incompatible features in your application.